# Java SWT List - make it unselectable

Tags: java, swt

I wish to use org.eclipse.swt.widgets.List just to present some data. User should not be allowed to select any item.

I could just:

```
List list = new List(this, SWT.V_SCROLL);
list.setEnabled(false);
```

But then I will loose scrolling feature. How can I just make list items unselectable?

Answer (score 6):

Another alternative is to use a `Table` instead of `List` and disable selection painting like this:

```
table.addListener(SWT.EraseItem, new Listener() {
    @Override
    public void handleEvent(Event event) {
        event.detail &= ~SWT.SELECTED;
        event.detail &= ~SWT.HOT;
    }
});
```

Comment: You still get the focus rectangle for the "selected" item, but that's a good thing: you can navigate with the keyboard in the list. This better then my proposed solutions. Here's a plus vote.

Comment: @andi I haven't tried but you can probably get rid of this by AND-NOT-ing the `SWT.FOCUSED` flag.

Answer (score 1):

You could try to clear selection each time user selects an item. The selection will be visible for a short time interval, though.

```
    list.addListener(SWT.Selection, new Listener() {
        @Override
        public void handleEvent(Event event) {
            list.setSelection(new String[0]);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't like my other answer with clearing selection, you could try to keep the list disabled, but inside a `ScrolledComposite`. It will look disabled, but scrolling will work. Here is a snippet:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    final Display display = new Display();
    final Shell shell = new Shell(display);
    shell.setLayout(new FillLayout());

    final ScrolledComposite scrolledComposite = new ScrolledComposite(shell, SWT.H_SCROLL | SWT.V_SCROLL);
    scrolledComposite.setExpandHorizontal(true);
    scrolledComposite.setExpandVertical(true);
    scrolledComposite.setBackground(display.getSystemColor(SWT.COLOR_CYAN));
    final List list = new List(scrolledComposite, SWT.NONE);
    list.setEnabled(false);
    scrolledComposite.setContent(list);
    scrolledComposite.addListener(SWT.Resize, new Listener() {
        @Override
        public void handleEvent(Event event) {
            final Point size = list.computeSize(SWT.DEFAULT, SWT.DEFAULT, true);
            scrolledComposite.setMinSize(size);
        }
    });

    for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
        list.add(Integer.toString(i));
    }

    shell.open();
    while (!shell.isDisposed()) {
        if (!display.readAndDispatch()) {
            display.sleep();
        }
    }
    display.dispose();
}
```

Arrow keys and page up/down down do not work, so you will have to register key listeners and implement scrolling with keyboard.